# Get all contents of stream socket with fgets() in blocking mode

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, stream

In order to complete the handshaking for Websockets in ssl, the socket must be read in blocking mode. Using stream sockets, communication is done from the php backend with the (javascript) client using `fwrite()` and `fgets()`. In blocking mode, `fgets()` will wait until the next line comes in, and grab one line. Once the socket connection is made, the client sends the PHP some headers so that the handshake can be completed. The problem is, I can't think of a way to find where the end of the headers are, since the order depends on the browser being used.

I used this work around for chrome (since the sec-websocket-extensions line is the last header sent)

```
stream_set_blocking($lsSocketNew, true);
$lcHeader = "";
while($lcLine = fgets($lsSocketNew)){
  $lcHeader .= $lcLine;
  if(strstr($lcLine, "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions")){
    break;
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work in other browsers like firefox, where this header is the first one sent. :P

(I think `fread()` is supposed to do what I am looking for -- in blocking mode it is supposed to get "everything" on the socket when it comes in... but when I tried fread instead, it was returning a blank string. :P `stream_get_contents()` was the same )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't give you a PHP advice, there is a couple of things that you may want to consider:

**I.** What kind of "everything" are you looking for? There are no message borders in TCP so "everything in the stream" is equivalent to "random ordered amount of data". Unfortunately, you aren't going to magically read all HTTP headers and stop there.

**II.** Given point I, you have to find something that separates HTTP headers from an HTTP body. This is actually rather simple, because the headers end with a [blank line](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html). So, just read the data until you receive `CRLF CRLF`*. In PHP you will most probably see `CRLF` as `\n`, though this can depend on the OS.

**III.** If you're implementing websockets, using `fgets` is questionable, because the rest of the protocol (after HTTP handshake) is binary. You may want to use dedicated PHP's sockets module and [`socket_recv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php) instead of `fread`. I can't say how these two functions differ, but `socket_*` functions are just a wrapper around BSD sockets which are implemented in a wide variety of languages. Since they're mostly language agnostic, you will find more support and tutorials in the internet.

---

* Per the HTTP standard:

```
CR = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
LF = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
```

Comment: looking for a blank line like you said in (II) was exactly what I was looking for.

I get what you are saying in (III), but `socket_recv()` only works for sockets that aren't stream sockets. Stream sockets have a function called `stream_get_content()`, but as far as I can tell, this doesn't support blocking, which is required to complete a ssl handshake. I tried various methods, using `fgets()` was the one that worked.